# ReactRouter v6: Why do nested routes work for some paths but not others resulting in error 404?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently learning how to use `react-router` v6. I'm creating nested routes for my `App` but they don't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code from the router:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(
  <Route path="/" element={<Root />}>
    <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
    <Route path="articles" element={<Articles />} />
    <Route path="articles/:title" element={<Article/>} />
    <Route path="categories" element={<Categories />} />
      <Route path=":name" element={<Category/>} />
    <Route/>
    <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
      <Route path="edit" element={<EditProfileForm />} />
    <Route />
    <Route path="authors/:name" element={<Author />}/>
  </Route>
))

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </>
  );
}
```

The first nested row of routes (about, sign-up ...) work just fine but when I try to go for `"/categories/:name"` or `"profile/edit"` all I get is an error 404, and I can't understand why.

And I bet you guys know why !

I took them off the nested routes and gave them an absolute path and it works, it just won't work as a child route with a relative path

Here is a screen of the app:

[image: app screen in Cayegory nested Route]

I'm on the nested route `Categories` and I want to hit the concepts link which should send me to a page rendering the sub-category but all I get is an error 404 instead:

[image: error 404 when trying to load a nestedRoute within category]

Here is a link to a codesandbox with my project running [link to codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/GauthierJeannenot/reactRouter/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cli01mbvw000a356k67k4vl3l%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cli01mbvw000c356kca6ebt3v%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cli01mbvw000a356k67k4vl3l%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cli01mbvw0009356k19c27l4f%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cli01mbvw000a356k67k4vl3l%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cli01mbvw0009356k19c27l4f%2522%257D%252C%2522cli01mbvw000c356kca6ebt3v%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cli01mbvw000c356kca6ebt3v%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cli01n7h100c6356kzlbh9op0%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cli01n42p0079356k6s7kdj03%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cli01n7h100c6356kzlbh9op0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

Comment: Do all parent routes of nested routes components, e.g. `Categories` and `Profile`, render an `Outlet` for the nested routes? Do you want these components to render at the same time as their nested route components?

Comment: Yes they do, but the problem comes even before the rendering of the component as the page loads to an error 404

Comment: That's something on the server then. Servers return 404s. How are you building and hosting/serving the app?

Comment: it's a local deployment using the create-react-app local development server, there is absolutely no back-end in my App

Comment: So how are you running and serving the app?

Comment: I'm sorry as a beginner i'm having a hard time understanding your question, the app is not online i'm running it through the npm start command

Comment: So what exactly is returning a 404 error? Can you [edit] to share the error you are facing? If necessary/possible, think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: there you are, i updated the post with a link to a codeSandbox running my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to nest routes and build the paths up relatively, then the `Route` components actually need to be nested within a parent `Route`. You can't just *indent* a route and expect it to be nested. You are rendering empty `Route` components instead of opening and closing tags.

The current code:

```
<Route path="categories" element={<Categories />} /> // <-- closed
<Route path=":name" element={<Category />} />
<Route /> // <-- empty
<Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} /> // <-- closed
<Route path="edit" element={<EditProfileForm />} />
<Route /> // <-- empty
```

Should be:

```
<Route path="categories" element={<Categories />}> // <-- open tag
  <Route path=":name" element={<Category />} />
</Route> // <-- closing tag
<Route path="profile" element={<Profile />}> // <-- open tag
  <Route path="edit" element={<EditProfileForm />} />
</Route> // <-- closing tag
```

Full routes example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<Root />}>
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
      <Route path="articles" element={<Articles />} />
      <Route path="articles/:title" element={<Article />} />
      <Route path="categories" element={<Categories />}>
        <Route path=":name" element={<Category />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />}>
        <Route path="edit" element={<EditProfileForm />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="authors/:name" element={<Author />} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```